Visual studio Installer use Publish output rather than build output
I'm using Visual studio Installer to generate an MSI file of a .Net Project.
I don't want external packages as dependencies. I can easily achieve it by using "Publish" in VS and setting the output as self contained.
I'm also using VS installer to generate an installer but it simply uses the DEBUG/RELEASE build output which isn't self-contained, is there a way to use the "Publish" output instead?

In the publish settings, have you chosen Folder as the target?

Yes, it's a folder

are you using this? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2022InstallerProjects

yes, I'm using that extension.

The only solution I have found is remove the publish output and then import every file from the publish folder.
